# FullCalendar updateEvent

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using fullCalendar V3.0.1 plugin for a project and i'm struggling with the `updateEvent` method. 
My task at hand is to manually change the `timeRange` of a particular event.
The problem is that it only works with start time. If i update `endTime` to, i got and

> Uncaught TypeError: "Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined"*

Here is my code

```
timeRange = this.newDate(time);

event.title = title;
event.start = moment(timeRange.start);
event.end = moment(timeRange.end);

$(this.target).fullCalendar('updateEvents', event);
$(this.target).fullCalendar('rerenderEvents');
```

***Note that `newDate()` return 2 Js Date object. One for start time an the other for end time.

Comment: have a look at this fiddle  http://jsfiddle.net/100thgear/h9cc6/

Comment: Thanks for your answer!!! I solved my problem by using new Date() instead of moment and it works fine !!

Comment: @EaBangalore Your link does not work anymore, please post an answer instead.